# Get name of img from for loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have the following code to display the images:

```
_image = [[imagesModel alloc] initFromURLWithString:imageURL completion:^(id model, JSONModelError *err) {
    int x = 0;
    int w = 1;

    for (imageModel *img in _image.Images)
    {

        NSString *picString = [NSString stringWithFormat:picURL, img.filename];
        NSLog(@"Images: %@", picString);

        UIImage *getImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picString]]];
        UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:getImage];
        self.pictureScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w * 123, 120);
        imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(x * 123, 1, 120, 120);
        x++;
        w++;
        [pictureScroll addSubview:imageView2];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        clicked = img.filename; 
        // hide the loader view
    }
        [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];
}];
```

When the user clicks on an image I want the user to go to a new view where they can see the image full size (it's a thumbnail now).

I open a new view now, but it opens the last images (Dùh).
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, my brains are a mess at the moment :/

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use the [tag:xcode] tag unless you have an issue with the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One day later I found the answer by myself here:

[tap gesture recognizer - which object was tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573036/tap-gesture-recognizer-which-object-was-tapped)

I added right below the int w = 0

```
int c = 0;
```

in the for loop I added 2 lines of code

```
imageView2.tag = c;
c++;
```

Now I get an int depending on wich item is clicked. I use this int to get a filename for an array.